# Space in a folder, terminal can't cd

Tags: bash, terminal, macbookpro-touch-bar

Macbook Pro 13" 2016, High Sierra 10.13.2

I know that terminal cannot open/cd folders with spaces unless there is exis symbol `\`, or `" "` around space or the whole folder name. However, terminal and iTerm still having an issue with that.

`*****:~ #######$ cd /Users/#######Google\ Drive 
-bash: cd: /Users/#######/Google: No such file or directory
*****:~ #######$ cd Google\ Drive/
-bash: cd: Google: No such file or directory
*****:~ #######$ cd Google' 'Drive/
-bash: cd: Google: No such file or directory
*****:~ #######$ cd 'Google Drive'/
-bash: cd: Google: No such file or directory
*****:~ #######$ cd "Google Drive"
-bash: cd: Google: No such file or directory
*****:~ #######$ cd Google" "Drive
-bash: cd: Google: No such file or directory`

Google Drive is visible with `ls`.

Google Drive is also typed with auto-completion (type `Goo` and press enter) and drag-n-drop of folder from Finder to Terminal, where terminal inserts `\` itself and it gives you `Google\ Drive/`.

This behavior is relevant to, probably, all folders on my mac. This happens for a while already and I want to solve it.

P.S. Problem occurs primarily for `cd` command.

upd.

As requested, here's the output of 
    stivens ~ $ ls -d Google*Drive | xxd
    00000000: 476f 6f67 6c65 2044 7269 7665 0a         Google Drive.

and `type cd`

```
stivens ~ $ type cd
cd is a function
cd ()
{
    unset RETVAL;
    if __gvm_is_function __gvm_oldcd; then
        __gvm_oldcd $*;
    fi;
    local dot_go_version dot_go_pkgset rslt;
    local defaults_go_name defaults_go_pkgset;
    local defaults_resolved=false;
    local defaults_hash;
    defaults_hash=();
    if [[ "$GVM_ROOT" == "" ]]; then
        __gvm_display_error "GVM_ROOT not set. Please source \$GVM_ROOT/scripts/gvm";
        return $?;
    fi;
    [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Resolving defaults...";
    __gvm_read_environment_file "${GVM_ROOT}/environments/default" > /dev/null;
    rslt=$?;
    defaults_hash=(${RETVAL});
    if [[ $rslt -eq 0 ]]; then
        defaults_resolved=true;
    else
        [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Can't find default environment. Falling back to system.";
        __gvm_read_environment_file "${GVM_ROOT}/environments/system" > /dev/null;
        rslt=$?;
        defaults_hash=(${RETVAL});
        if [[ $rslt -eq 0 ]]; then
            defaults_resolved=true;
        else
            [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Can't find system environment.";
        fi;
    fi;
    if [[ "${defaults_resolved}" == false ]]; then
        [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Resolving fallback go version and pkgset from all available.";
        local fallback_go_version="";
        __gvm_resolve_fallback_version > /dev/null;
        fallback_go_version="${RETVAL}";
        local fallback_go_pkgset="";
        __gvm_resolve_fallback_pkgset "${fallback_go_version}" > /dev/null;
        fallback_go_pkgset="${RETVAL}";
        {
            setValueForKeyFakeAssocArray "gvm_go_name" "${fallback_go_version}" "${defaults_hash[*]}" > /dev/null;
            defaults_hash=(${RETVAL});
            setValueForKeyFakeAssocArray "gvm_pkgset_name" "${fallback_go_pkgset}" "${defaults_hash[*]}" > /dev/null;
            defaults_hash=(${RETVAL})
        };
        unset fallback_go_version;
        unset fallback_go_pkgset;
        defaults_resolved=true;
    fi;
    defaults_go_name="";
    defaults_go_pkgset="";
    {
        valueForKeyFakeAssocArray "gvm_go_name" "${defaults_hash[*]}" > /dev/null;
        defaults_go_name="${RETVAL}";
        valueForKeyFakeAssocArray "gvm_pkgset_name" "${defaults_hash[*]}" > /dev/null;
        defaults_go_pkgset="${RETVAL}"
    };
    if [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "Resolved default go: ${defaults_go_name:-[EMPTY]}";
        echo "Resolved default pkgset: ${defaults_go_pkgset:-[EMPTY]}";
    fi;
    __gvmp_find_closest_dot_go_version > /dev/null;
    rslt=$?;
    dot_go_version="${RETVAL}";
    if [[ $rslt -eq 0 ]]; then
        [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Found dot_go_version: ${dot_go_version}";
        local use_goversion="";
        __gvmp_read_dot_go_version "${dot_go_version}" > /dev/null;
        use_goversion="${RETVAL}";
        [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Switching to: ${use_goversion}";
        \gvm use --quiet "${use_goversion}" || return 1;
        unset use_goversion;
    else
        if [[ -n "${defaults_go_name}" ]]; then
            [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "No .go-version found. Using system or default go.";
            \gvm use --quiet "${defaults_go_name}" || return 1;
        else
            if [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]]; then
                local installed_hash;
                installed_hash=();
                __gvm_find_installed "" "${GVM_ROOT}/gos" > /dev/null;
                installed_hash=(${RETVAL});
                local go_archive_path="$GVM_ROOT/archive/go";
                echo "No fallback go version could be found.";
                if [[ ${#installed_hash[@]} -eq 0 && ! -d "${go_archive_path}" ]]; then
                    __gvm_locale_text_for_key "go_install_prompt" > /dev/null;
                    __gvm_display_error "${RETVAL}";
                    return 1;
                fi;
                unset go_archive_path;
                unset installed_hash;
            fi;
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;
    __gvmp_find_closest_dot_go_pkgset > /dev/null;
    rslt=$?;
    dot_go_pkgset="${RETVAL}";
    if [[ $rslt -eq 0 ]]; then
        [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Found .go-pkgset: ${dot_go_pkgset}";
        local use_gopkgset="";
        __gvmp_read_dot_go_pkgset "${dot_go_pkgset}" > /dev/null;
        use_gopkgset="${RETVAL}";
        [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "Switching to: ${use_gopkgset}";
        \gvm pkgset use --quiet "${use_gopkgset}" || return 1;
        unset use_gopkgset;
    else
        if [[ -n "${defaults_go_pkgset}" ]]; then
            [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "No .go-pkgset found. Using system or default pkgset.";
            \gvm pkgset use --quiet "${defaults_go_pkgset}" || return 1;
        else
            [[ "${GVM_DEBUG}" -eq 1 ]] && echo "No fallback pkgset could be found.";
        fi;
    fi;
    return 0
}
```

`command cd Google\ Drive/` does work, `\cd Google\ Drive/` does not though.

Comment: Run `type cd` and see what it says. It sounds like you've added a buggy custom function for it

Comment: I concur with the previous comment; the symptoms certainly look like you have a nonstandard `cd`. It is possible that you *in addition* have a whitespace character which isn't actually a regular ASCII space in the folder name. See if `ls -d Google*Drive | xxd` reveals anything unusual (a regular space is hex `20` while some other Unicode whitespace would be a complex thing spanning several bytes, or perhaps a control character).

Comment: You can temporarily override the buggy `cd` with `command cd Google\ Drive/` or `\cd Google\ Drive/`.

Comment: For one thing, `__gvm_oldcd $*` should be `__gvm_oldcd "$@"`.

Comment: How do you change `__gvm_oldcd $*` to `__gvm_oldcd "$@"`? And how to fix `cd` in general? What could have caused the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I figured out what caused the issue.

I noticed `GVM` occurrence in `type cd` and recalled that at some point I installed Go Version Manager, aka GVM, and found a script parser in .bash_profile `[[ -s "/Users/stivens/.gvm/scripts/gvm" ]] && source "/Users/stivens/.gvm/scripts/gvm"`.

I just commented it out and now `cd` works properly.

Bazinga!